# Textmate Cucumber "Undefined Step" even though it exists

Tags: ruby, cucumber, textmate

After having a lot of issues with Textmate and Cucumber, I've gone through a lot of steps of reinstalling git so that I could update and install a later version of ruby on rvm, changing from the rvm-auto-ruby to rvm-wrapper, I am now getting it to run but 'Undefined step'

Hoever, the step exists and my guard reads it all fine.

- I am using the latest rvm and ruby-head
- I am using cucumber/cucumber-rails 1.0.2
- It is definitely using the right Ruby/Gemset

**tl;dr**

Cucumber Bundle is not reading my steps when I hit Run.

Comment: Perhaps some sample code, or complete error messages would help people answer your question.

Comment: What code would you want? All my Cucumber tests are pending because it's not finding any of my steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `config/cucumber.yml` you might need to add `--require features` in the standard options, it will probably have a line like this:

```
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip"
```

Change it to read

```
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --require features --tags ~@wip"
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Any idea why it is no there by default?

Comment: Yes, I sent them the patch and it broke their own features :P You can comment on the pull request here. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/pull/157

Comment: Thanks so much, this `--require features` saved me with undefined features when trying to run Cucumber via the Rake task!